# Capture label of actionButton in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

What's the best way to get the label of an **actionButton** that is clicked? I have an **actionButton** that has the label updated. When the user clicks, I need to capture that. I tried  input$action2.label and input$action2.text, but neither worked.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI( fluidPage(

tags$head(tags$style(
  HTML('
       { background-color: #dec4de;}
       #action4 { width: 275 px; color:red; background-color:yellow }
       #action1, #action2, #action3 { color:black; background-color:lime }
       body, label, input, button, select { font-family: "Arial"; }'
  )
)),    

titlePanel("My Shiny App!"),

sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                tabPanel("About", "Developer Info here"), 
                tabPanel("How to Use", "User Docs"))

  ),

  mainPanel(
    img(src="capstone1.jpg", align = "center"),
    br(),br(),
    tags$textarea(id="stext", rows=3, cols=80, "Default value"),
    br(),br(),br(),
    actionButton("action1", "Action 1"),
    actionButton("action2", "Action 2"),
    actionButton("action3", "Action 3"),
    br(), br(),
    actionButton("action4", 
                   label = "High < < < <  PROBABILITY  > > > > Low")
  )
)))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {

   observeEvent(input$action1, {
      x <- input$stext
      print(input$action2.text)
      updateTextInput(session, "stext", value=paste(x, "Btn 1"))
   })

   observeEvent(input$action2, {
      x <- input$stext
      print(input$action2.label)
      updateTextInput(session, "stext", value=paste(x, "Btn 2"))
   })  

   observeEvent(input$action3, {
      x <- input$stext
      print(x)
      updateTextInput(session, "stext", value=paste(x, "Btn 3"))
   })  

})
```

UPDATE: Adding code for shinyBS

**ui.R**

```
{
   library(shinyBS)
   ....
   bsButton("myBtn", "")
   ...

}
```

**server.R**

```
{
     ....
     updateButton(session, "myBtn", "New Label")
     ....
}
```

Comment: When I create that action button and store it as an object and explore, I see that this - ab$children[[1]][[2]] gives you the label name. Can you try if input$action1$children[[1]][[2]] gives you what you need?

Comment: Looking at this source code, the icon and label are stored as a list in the shiny tags. So, it makes sense that the label is obtained as the second element of that list. https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/R/input-action.R

Comment: @user3949008, I got the error "Warning: Unhandled error in observer: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
observeEvent(input$action1)"

Comment: I am also struggling to find a way to change the label of the actionButton. Hopefully the solution here might also be helpful there.

Comment: I have switched to shinyBS and used bsButton. Now I can update the label of the button, but still not able to read the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to update the label **(A)**, without using shinyBs, in ui.R you can use `textOutput()`, then to read and catch the click of the user **(B)**, in server.R you can use `observeEvent()` and `updateTextInput()` but starting from the initial result of your function.

**(A) Updating the label of the buttons :**

```
p(
  actionButton("controller1", label=textOutput("option1")),
  actionButton("controller2", label=textOutput("option2")),
  actionButton("controller3", label=textOutput("option3")),
  style="text-align: center;"),
```

with in server.R

```
output$option1 <- renderPrint({
    if(input$userText %in% c("", " ")){cat("waiting")}  ## to avoid bad readings.

    else{cat(myFunction(input$userText)[1])}            ## here use the first element of 
                                                        ## the result of your function.
})

output$option2 <- renderPrint({
    if(input$userText %in% c("", " ")){cat("for")}
    else{cat(myFunction(input$userText)[2])}
})

output$option3 <- renderPrint({
    if(input$userText %in% c("", " ")){cat("you")}
    else{cat(myFunction(input$userText)[3])}
})
```

**(B) To read and catch the click of the user :**

```
shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$controller1, {
        if(input$userText %in% c("", " ")){x <- "waiting"}    ## to stay consistent
                                                              ## in case the user clicks.
        else{x <- myFunction(input$userText)[1]}

    updateTextInput(session, "userText", value = paste(input$userText, x))
    })

    observeEvent(input$controller2, {
        if(input$userText %in% c("", " ")){x <- "for"}
        else{x <- myFunction(input$userText)[2]}

    updateTextInput(session, "userText", value = paste(input$userText, x))
    })

    observeEvent(input$controller3, {
        if(input$userText %in% c("", " ")){x <- "you"}
        else{x <- myFunction(input$userText)[3]}

    updateTextInput(session, "userText", value = paste(input$userText, x))
    })

})
```

Comment: Thanks Gwenael. After looking at your code, I found that I can just create a array object that I can use to store the label when i update the button. So I can get the label by accessing the element in the array at that index.